# ionic iframe ng-src youtube video link not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, ionic-framework

I am new to Ionic, I am trying to build an app  with ionic 1.
Everything is working fine except video URL in ng-src. Here is my code

```
$scope.trustSrc = function(src) {
    return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(src);
  }
<iframe width="100%" height="315" ng-src="{{trustSrc(guide.video_url)}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

**Refused to display 'youtube.com/watch?v=4me16JMuBbs'; in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'**

Comment: what is an error??

Comment: @WasiqMuhammad this is the error i am getting Refused to display 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4me16JMuBbs' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Answer (score 2):

You should modify your video URL to the embeddable version:

This is your URL that doesn't work because YouTube doesn't allow to embed it into an iFrame

```
youtube.com/watch?v=4me16JMuBbs
```

This is the correct URL

```
youtube.com/embed/4me16JMuBbs
```

For **YouTube** you can do it this way (you should test if every URL has the same format)

```
url.replace('watch?v=', 'embed/')
```

For **Vimeo** you can do it this way (you should test it too):

```
url.replace('vimeo.com', 'player.vimeo.com/video')
```

Comment: data is coming from database, user can upload any youtube or vimeo url

Comment: i think i have to convert the url in controller...let me try... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<iframe width="100%" height="315" ng-bind-html="trustAsResourceUrl" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>


in your controller first add `'$sce' then

$scope.trustSrc = function(src) {
$scope.trustAsResourceUrl = $sce.trustAsHtml(//Your URL code);

}
```

**OR**

```
<iframe width="100%" height="315" src="{{trustAsResourceUrl}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```